# Creating custom UITableView table cells from inside cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios5, uitableview

Very curious how to handle custom table cells from inside tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:.

I instantiate a custom table cell in viewDidLoad. My question is how do I handle the situation in cellForRowAtIndexPath when there isn't a reusable cell? For example, when returning a search result. How do I create a new custom cell, if needed? I included the pertinent methods below.

Thanks

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   //Load custom table cell
     UINib *customCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomItem" bundle:nil];

   //Register this nib, which contains the cell
    [[self tableView] registerNib:customCellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomItemCell"];


   //.... More stuff here

  }


  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

     CustomItemCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomItemCell"];

     // If there is no reusable cell of this type, create a new one
     if (!cell) {


       //Is this right?
       cell = [[CustomItemCell alloc] init];

     }




          //Set up cell with data here...



    return cell;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by accessing the main bundle, looking for the custom table cell nib file. When we find our custom table cell class, we assign iVar "cell" to that object.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   static NSString *cellID = @"CustomItemCell";
   CustomItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

   // If there is no reusable cell of this type, create a new one

   if(cell == nil){


    NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in nibObjects) {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomItemCell class]])
        {
            cell = (CustomItemCell *)currentObject;

        }


    }

  } 
   //Assign data to cell here   
}
```